# Converging sequences with real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Is this theorem correct or not and how would you prove it:

If $(a_{n}^{2})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to a positive real number $l$, then $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to square root of $l$.

Comment: $a_n=(-1)^n{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is false. But something weaker is true. Note that if $a_{n}^{2}\to l$, then since square root is a continuous function, we have $|a_{n}|=\sqrt{a_{n}^{2}}\to \sqrt{l}$. So we can't necessarily say that $a_{n}\to \sqrt{l}$ but what we can say is that $|a_n|\to \sqrt{l}$.

For a counter example consider something like $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ for all $n$. Then $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge but $a_{n}^{2}=1$ for all $n$, so $(a_{n}^{2})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.